# IE8 stripping ID attributes, huh?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, attributes

When using jQuery to insert HTML into a div in IE8, IE8 strips the ID tags and certain class names in the HTML.

Here is a sample. I am inserting this code using jQuery (1.6.2)

```
var oblSomeoneElseHTML = 
'<div id="oblSomeoneElse">' +
'  <h2>Enter the name and email of a person you\'d like<br/>to purchase a registration for:</h2>'+
'<form class="voucher_form" id="voucher_form">'+
'  <div class="inputrow"><label class="l1">Student Alliance Member #:</label> <input type="text" id="customer_id" name="customer_id" class="oblSomeoneElseCustID"/></div><br>'+
'  <div class="inputrow"><label class="l1">Student First Name:<em>*</em></label> <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" class="validate[required] oblSomeoneElseFirstName"/></div><br>'+
'  <div class="inputrow"><label class="l1">Student Last Name:<em>*</em></label> <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" class="validate[required] oblSomeoneElseLastName"/></div><br>'+
'  <div class="inputrow"><label class="l1">Student Date of Birth:<em>*</em></label> <input type="text" id="DOB" name="DOB" class="validate[required,custom[MMDDYYYY]] oblSomeoneElseDOB"/></div><br>'+
'  <div class="inputrow"><label class="l1">Student Email:<em>*</em></label> <input type="text" id="SomeoneElseEmail" name="SomeoneElseEmail" class="validate[required,custom[email] oblSomeoneElseEmail"/></div><br>'+
'  <a href="#" class="btn btncenter oblsomeoneelsenext">Next</a>'+
'  <div class="spinner"><img src="/images/grey_spinner.gif"></div>'+
'</form>'+
'<img src="/images/blank.gif" width="20" height="20" alt="" border="0" style="position: relative; left: 5px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="clearPrompts();">'+
'</div>';

  $('#sm_content .oblcontent').html(oblSomeoneElseHTML);
```

Now, when I am debugging the validation of the DOB input and view the value of oblSomeoneElseHTML in the Watch window, it shows the ID and the correct class attributes. 
I am using validationEngine plugin to validate this form and it REQUIRES the ID tag to work.

```
<input type="text" id="DOB" name="DOB" class="validate[required,custom[MMDDYYYY]] oblSomeoneElseDOB"/></div>
```

But, when I debug into the validationEngine code, this, in the _getPrompt() function:

```
 var className = field.attr("id").replace(":","_") + "formError";
```

returns this error:

```
'attr(...)' is null or not an object
```

When I evaluate the field object, I see no id value and I see only class oblSomeoneElseDOB.

I am at a loss as to what is happening here and why this is only happening in IE8. IE7 and IE9 work perfectly, FF and Chrome and Opera work perfectly, too.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: isnt __field__ the reference to the old DOM node?

Comment: in jQuery it is defined and assigned like this:                      var field = $(this);

Comment: Yes, but where are you setting the __field__ before or after you replaced the whole .oblcontent? an example is: $("#field").replaceWith("<div id='field'>lorem</div>").hide() it wont hide the new #field with the text lorem, here is an example: http://jsbin.com/ehazib/edit

Comment: Please include the actual code that is having the problem, not just the single line, but the whole context, including how you're assigning the variable `field` and how you're inserting the HTML in question.

Comment: [quote]Yes, but where are you setting the field before or after you replaced the whole .oblcontent? [/quote] That is rather irrelevant because the validation couldn't fire UNTIL the field has already been viewable to the user and they entered it.

Comment: [quote]Please include the actual code that is having the problem[/quote] You can test at this URL: http://www.scic.com/schedule select Texas as state and click register for the first class in Austin, use DPAYNE userid and pay111 as password when requested to login. Then when the dialog comes up asking "for Me" or "For Someone Else", select "For Someone Else". place your cursor in the DOB field and then hit the tab key to cursor out. The validation would happen on the DOB field at that point. remember, this only happens in IE8.

Comment: OK, The problem caused me to have to revert back to using our old validator. I've narrowed it down to the code that is actually assigning the HTML. The original had the div oblSomeoneElse in an included file and not generated. I reverted back to that and testing on our test server, it works in IE8, somewhat. The only problem now lies in the fact that when calling field.width() in IE8, it returns 0. In all the other browsers it returns the width of the field. this makes the validation error prompt show off screen because of the way it's position is calculated.

Comment: Ive tried dozens of things to get it to work to no avail.

Comment: BTW, doctype is: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Comment: Decided to go another route because no real solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverted back to using the form already built in the html, not generated through javascript, and everything works now. We did things a little differently but it is working like a charm.